# Determining the correct origin to rotate a QPolygonF around

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, polygon

Edit: Added more information.

I'd like to rotate a `QPolygonF` around the origin illustrated below:

[image: block rotations]

I'd like this polygon (centre of image is origin - `0, 0`):

[image: first polygon]

To rotate clockwise so that it ends up here:

[image]

The `QPolygonF` has points in the same position as the first block in the image above:

```
QPolygonF p1 =  QPolygonF() << QPointF(0, 1) << QPointF(4, 1) << QPointF(4, 2) << QPointF(0, 2);
```

I then rotate around what I think is the correct origin (`2, 2`):

```
QTransform t;
t.translate(2, 2);
t.rotate(-90);
t.translate(-2, -2);
QPolygonF p2 = t.map(p1);
qDebug() << p1 << "rotated = " << p2;
```

Output:

```
QPolygonF(QPointF(0, 1) QPointF(4, 1) QPointF(4, 2) QPointF(0, 2) ) rotated =  QPolygonF(QPointF(1, 4) QPointF(1, 0) QPointF(2, 0) QPointF(2, 4) )
```

When the output that I want is:

```
QPolygonF(QPointF(0, 1) QPointF(4, 1) QPointF(4, 2) QPointF(0, 2) ) rotated =  QPolygonF(QPointF(2, 0) QPointF(3, 0) QPointF(3, 4) QPointF(2, 4) )
```

But, according to the output above, the polygon would end up looking like this:

[image: wrong rotation]

At which point should I be rotating around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

After working out what you are after I now know the right code to achieve this:

```
QTransform t; 
t.translate(2, 2); 
t.rotate(90); 
t.translate(-2, -2); 
QPolygonF p2 = t.map(p1); 
qDebug() << p1 << "rotated = " << p2;
```

Which will give the rectangle:

```
QPolygonF(QPointF(3, 0) QPointF(3, 4) QPointF(2, 4) QPointF(2, 0) )
```

Which is what you expect (although the ordering is change due the rotation). It's worth noting that `rotate(90)` and `rotate(-90)` will not give the same result as you are rotating about the *edge* of the rectangle, not the *middle* of it.

**Conceptualising QT tranforms**

Some confusion may arise because of the direction of the qt [rotate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtransform.html#rotate) function. Although this will enact a counter clockwise rotation, because we "see" the y-axis inverted (at least in this case) it appears clockwise to us.

As an analogy if I'm in a room and observer a lamp falling over to the left,
from the point of view of someone hanging on the cieling it has "fallen over" to the right.

Comment: The points are correct as they are because I want the polygon to rotate in a certain way - as seen in the first image I posted. I tried using `(2, 3)` as my pivot but it gave me this output which is not what I'm after: `{(0, 4), (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 4)}`. What I'm after is points at [these locations](http://i.imgur.com/q2lra.png).

Comment: Ah, then in that case you want to translate about `(2,1)`. (You want to translate from your top left `(0, 1)` to the midpoint `(2, 2)`. `(2, 2) - (0, 1) = (2, 1)`. I have amended my original answer

Comment: Doing that [gives me](http://pastebin.com/Ezfn0kmW): `{(2, 3), (2, -1), (3, -1), (3, 3)}`. Just to confirm, the origin is originally `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Have you tried your original approach but with `rotate(90)` instead of `rotate(-90)`.

Comment: Yep, but that just rotates it counter-clockwise. I've updated my question to add more information.

Comment: Yes, you are rotating it to the `-90` position (`QPolygonF(QPointF(1, 4) QPointF(1, 0) QPointF(2, 0) QPointF(2, 4) )`), but you actually want the `90` position (`QPolygonF(QPointF(2, 0) QPointF(3, 0) QPointF(3, 4) QPointF(2, 4) )`).

These won't be equivilent, because you are "above" the origin after translation, not directly on top of it.

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10164/discussion-between-mitch-and-cmh).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me further cmh. I'm still a bit foggy on that line in Qt's rotate documentation, so I've opened [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192651/understanding-qts-qtransform-rotate-function) regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

I had just a short look, but I think this is wrong:

```
t.translate(2, 2);
```

To obtain your transformation should be:

```
t.translate(2, 1);
```

The lower bound of the rectangle is at y = 1, as far as I understand ...

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work. The bottom y coordinate of the original rectangle/polygon is 2. I've updated my question to hopefully convey my question better.